# how do I calculate average value of columns of a file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe

I am trying to get the average of item prices in this data file.

```
order_id      quantity   item_name      item_price
0              1          pizza          34.2 
1              1          chips          2.3
2              2          cola           2.0
3              3          burger         10.2
4              1          tart           6.43
....
.... 
more data rows
```

```
import pandas as pd
my_file = pd.read_csv("file.tsv", sep="\t")
my_file.head()
my_file['item_price'].mean()
```

- I could easily do this by using Pandas. However, how could I do it
  without using Pandas?
- how do I loop file's columns
- how do I add them up?

I am new to Pandas and Python and I am trying to understand how accessing and evaluating data works.

my first approach was like:
`chip.shape gives me (4622, 5)` then I do this:

```
i = 0
a = 0
while i < 4622
    a += df.at[i, 'item_price']
    i += 1
avg = a/4622
print(avg)
```

but this is just erroneous. How can I loop the columns and average them in correct sytnax using DataFrames but not using mean function.

Comment: You say `chip.shape gives me (4622, 5)`, but I have no idea what `chip` is or where you got it from, or what it is suppose to have to do with the code you tried. Where you say "but this is just erroneous", how do you know? What happened when you tried the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: It seems like you  are still using Pandas to *read* the data, so that you still have a Dataframe. Yes? You should say so, or else explain what you are doing instead. It seems like you expect `df.at[i, 'item_price']` to get a cell value from the Dataframe. Did you try reading the documentation for `df.at`? Did you understand it? There are multiple typos in your code; one of the most important skills to learn right now is the skill of noticing that things "look wrong".

Comment: It's difficult to help you because "without using Pandas" could mean a few different things. In theory you could read the file data using only the standard library, and produce a different data structure instead of a Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it, I'll show two of them:

1. Take values of this column - it is a numpy array. It also has method `mean()`

```
    prices = my_file['item_price'].values
    prices.mean()
```

2. Take values of this column and calculate the average value manually

```
    prices = my_file['item_price'].values
    sum(prices) / len(prices)
```